# How to write airflow logs to Elasticsearch?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am using `Airflow 1.10.5`. Can't seem to find complete documentation or sample on how to setup remote logging using Elasticsearch. I saw [airflow documentation about logging](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/howto/write-logs.html), but it wasn't helpful. I am trying to write the airflow (not task) logs to ES.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand the docs, the ES log handler can only read from ES. You would have to setup your logging to print into a file, then use something like filebeat to post the file content to ES and Airflow can then read them back...

https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/howto/write-logs.html#writing-logs-to-elasticsearch

> Writing Logs to Elasticsearch
>
> Airflow can be configured to **read** task
>   logs from Elasticsearch and optionally write logs to stdout in
>   standard or json format. These logs can later be collected and
>   forwarded to the Elasticsearch cluster using tools like fluentd,
>   logstash or others.

Comment: Worst title ever for a section on _reading_ docs from elasticsearch: [Writing logs to Elasticsearch.](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/write-logs.html#writing-logs-to-elasticsearch)

Comment: is the title of the section truly wrong, or are we missunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve using `[filebeat][1]` shipper.

Input config section in `filebeat.yml`

```
</snip>

# ============================== Filebeat inputs ===============================

filebeat.inputs:

# Each - is an input. Most options can be set at the input level, so
# you can use different inputs for various configurations.
# Below are the input specific configurations.

- type: log

  # Change to true to enable this input configuration.
  enabled: true

  # Paths that should be crawled and fetched. Glob based paths.
  paths:
    - /path/to/logs/*.log

</snip>
```

Output config section in `filebeat.yml`

```
<snip>
# ---------------------------- Elasticsearch Output ----------------------------
output.elasticsearch:
  # Array of hosts to connect to.
  hosts: ["localhost:9200"]

  # Protocol - either `http` (default) or `https`.
  #protocol: "https"

  # Authentication credentials - either API key or username/password.
  #api_key: "id:api_key"
  username: "elastic"
  password: "changeme"

</snip>
```

Good [doc](https://medium.com/@semih.sezer/how-to-send-airflow-logs-to-elasticsearch-using-filebeat-and-logstash-250c074e7575) to read especially about airflow --> ES.